# How to capture return value from function in vim?

Tags: vim, return, return-value, capture

Example:

```
function! MyFunction()
  exe 'call Include("'.mykeyw.'")'
  Return value???
endfunction

function! Include(keyw)
   if condition == ""
     return 0
   endif
endfunction
```

If `return` in `Include()` is invoked I want to stop executing `MyFunction()`
as well.

It seems that there is no way other then checking the `return` value from the return statement from `Include()` in MyFunction.

But how do I check the return value from `Include()` in `MyFunction()`??

P.e. In this case, how do I capture the `return` value '0' from `Include()` in `MyFunction()`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Functions can be used as expressions; so you can simply store the return value of `Include()` in a variable or use it in a conditional:

```
function! MyFunction()
  let value = Include(mykeyw)    " stored as a variable
                                 " or
  if Include(mykeyw) == 1        " used in a conditional
    echo "Yay!"
  else
    echo "Nay!"
  endif
endfunction

function! Include(keyw)
  if condition == ""
    return 0
  endif
endfunction
```